# What precisely is the "silence" value in the SDL audio API?

Tags: audio, sdl

In SDL, when you set up your audio output device, you and SDL have to agree on an audio format - e.g. 44.1KHz stereo 16-bit signed little-endian. That's fine. But along with the final agreed format, you also get a computed "silence" value which doesn't seem well documented.

A silent sound sample obviously consist of the same sample value repeated over and over again, and you want that to be at the "zero" level. In a sense any constant value will do, but you have to agree a value (so you don't get pops when switching to a different sound), and in a sane world you want to choose a value bang in the centre of your sample-value range.

So if you happen to use an unsigned format for your sample value range for 0..whatever, your silence value will be (whatever/2).

**EDIT** - inserted "unsigned" below to avoid confusion.

That's all fine. But the silence value you get given is an unsigned 8-bit integer. That doesn't work very well if you want unsigned 16 bit samples - the logical silence value of 0x8000 requires two different byte values and it requires them to be in the correct endian order.

So the silence value you get from SDL doesn't seem to make much sense. You can't use it to wipe your buffers, for instance, without dealing with extra complications and making inferences which pretty much make the precalculated silence value pointless anyway.

Which means, of course, that I've misunderstood the point.

So - if this isn't how the silence value is meant to be used, how *should* it be used?

Comment: Minor nitpick, but if you're using 16-bit *signed* audio data, wouldn't the correct silence value be 0x0000 since the range is from -32k to +32k? I think you have a valid point for unsigned audio data however. My opinion on SDL's silence value is that it is probably just useless legacy cruft that you should quietly forget you ever saw, calculate your own and be on your merry way. :)

Comment: SDL supports 16 bit signed and unsigned, big and little endian. And the paragraph before established a context of using unsigned format with 0..whatever for sample values. But I could be more explicit - will fix.

Comment: Of course for signed samples, zeros just work as you say - but if all formats are expected to use zeros for silence, there's no point having the calculate silence value. Though... now you mention it, I'm not 100% that 16 bit samples can be unsigned (might be 8 bit only). I'll have to double check, but no time now - be back later.

Comment: @cecilkorik - on "legacy cruft" - maybe you're right, but one problem with multi-platform stuff is that tests done on your platforms don't mean something will work elsewhere. I tend to assume I've missed the point of something, because if I get dependent on an assumption that works in one place... An SDL example might be if you got dependent on initialising SDL audio without graphics on Linux. Go to Windows and the DirectX dependency kicks in, apparently meaning the graphics component must be initialised. Easy fix for that, of course, but some false assumptions are killers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no evidence to back this up but I think the assumption here is that "silence" could be interpreted as "silence for common soundcard formats".  Those being:

1. Unsigned 8-bit integers
2. Signed 16-bit integers
3. Signed 32-bit integers (for 24-bit audio data)
4. Normalized 32-bit floating point
5. Normalized 64-bit floating point.

In all the cases except for unsigned 8-bit,  zero (0) is the "zero amplitude" value.  So the returned unsigned 8-bit integer contains all the possible values of "zero amplitude" for these formats.

Comment: Sounds plausible, so accepted. From that, I guess I might consistency-check it with what I expect (zero or not).